# Apache mod_rewrite , suffix based to prefix based hosting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I'm working on a site hosted on apache. Users can access their webspace in the default way at www.hostname.com/~username.

I'm trying to change to username.hostname.com as it's a little cleaner. If users try to access the old www.hostname.com/~username addresses i'd like to just redirect them to the new ones. I don't know whether to use mod_alias or mod_rewrite rules?

Which one would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

`mod_alias` provides `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives.

> "simple redirection of one URL, or a class of URLs, to
>   somewhere else, should be accomplished using these directives rather
>   than RewriteRule. RedirectMatch allows you to include a regular
>   expression in your redirection criteria, providing many of the
>   benefits of using RewriteRule."
>
> "For example, all URLs in the /one directory must be redirected to
>   http://one.example.com/, or perhaps all http requests must be
>   redirected to https. These situations are better handled by the Redirect directive.
>   Remember that Redirect preserves path information. That is to say, a
>   redirect for a URL /one will also redirect all URLs under that, such
>   as /one/two.html and /one/three/four.html"
>
> [ [source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) ]

You can use something like this:

```
RedirectMatch /~([^/]+) http://$1.localhost/
```